# How to access struct field safely under multithread circumstances?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Image that i have a struct named

```
struct _Visitors{
    int totalNum;
    map<uintptr_t, Visitor*> visitorMap;
};
```

note that Visitor is a c++ class

then I declare a pointer pointing to an instance of struct _visitors, namely

```
struct _Visitors* pVisitors = NULL;
```

Now I have three threads: one main thread t1, two working thread t2 and t3.

t1 is something like this:

pVisitors = new _visitors();

t2 is something like this:

```
while(true){
     if a new visitor v enters
        //pthread_mutex_lock(mtx);
        pVisitors->totalNum++;
        visitorMap[v.getVid()] = &v;
        //pthread_mutex_unlock(mtx);
  }
```

t3 is something like this:

```
 while(true){
     if a new visitor v leaves
        //pthread_mutex_lock(mtx);
        pVisitors->totalNum--;
        visitorMap.eraseAt[v.getVid()];
        //pthread_mutex_unlock(mtx);
  }
```

I know that thread t1 and t2 may have data race on global instance of struct _Visitors, so I add an exclusive lock(mutex) to protect totalNum and visitorMap fields in struct _visitors.

Now my questions are: adding an exclusive lock to protect that fields in struct _Visitors is enough? If executing on a SMP architecture with multiple processors,  is it assured that my program will not encounter a data race at any conditions?

Comment: Not an answer, but names beginning with an underscore followed by a capital letter (and names containing two underscores) are reserved to the implementation. Don't use them.

Answer (score 0):

If your datas are properly protected by a mutex, I don't see any reason why you would have data races, SMP architecture or not.

Still, if you have any doubt about how you managed your mutex(es), do not hesitate to execute your program using valgrind, which is able to detect and warn you about data races.

Comment: Thanks! I am just in some extent of uncertainty on whether there is a data race. Your answer helps me eliminate my uncertainty.

Comment: Besides, valgrind is fine. I have used it for a quite while.